# LinearGradient in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use this code from Github in my app, but not sure why it shows some errors. A class to use later. It says The LinearGradient has a problem ( "colors, not defined ) but just checked the source code of Flutter and it has this property.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Palette {
  static const Color scaffold = Color(0xFFF0F2F5);

  static const Color facebookBlue = Color(0xFF1777F2);

  static const Gradient createRoomGradient = LinearGradient(
    colors: [Color(0xFF496AE1), Color(0xFFCE48B1)],
  );

  static const Color online = Color(0xFF4BCB1F);

  static const LinearGradient storyGradient = LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black26],
  );
}
```

Comment: which version of flutter you're running currently? Try restarting your pc and try again. If the problem persists then it looks like your Flutter package is corrupted. You need to reinstall from the start.

Comment: @OMiShah Thank you, man! So there is no problem with code itself . I just check other resources and  basically, all of them use Boxdecoration but cuz this is Class properties its not possible

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67084#issuecomment-702397222

> in your pubspec.yml
>
> change this to :
>
> environment: sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0" and flutter pub get
>
> i'm using android studio, then i invalidate cache and restart, done!

Comment: Hey, Ivan. Thank you. but didn't work for me. Is there any further step should have taken?

Comment: actually I set the environments: sdk: ">=2.10.0 < 3.0.0" and it is important to run "flutter pub get" thereafter and to restart the Dart Analysis Server (or the whole Android Studio as described in the original answer)

Answer (score 0):

The latest Flutter version (1.22.0) is broken, I'd say.

My LinearGradient code worked until 10 minutes ago. Then I updated Flutter.
After the update the same errors you see were coming up - no code changes were made.

However, the code still runs, regardless of the non-error, so that's the good news.